# $(X, T_1), (Y, T_2)$ be topological spaces such that every function from $X$ to $Y$ is $T_1-T_2$ continuous

Tags: general-topology

Let $(X, T_1), (Y, T_2)$ be topological spaces such that every function from 
$X$ to $Y$ is $T_1-T_2$ continuous. Prove that either $T_1$ is the discrete topology or $T_2$ is the indiscrete topology.

---

How can I do this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

HINT: Suppose that $T_1$ is not the discrete topology, and $T_2$ is not the indiscrete topology. This means that there is some point $x\in X$ such that $\{x\}$ is not an open set, and there is some $U\in T_2$ such that $\varnothing\ne U\ne Y$. Consequently, we can choose a point $y_0\in U$ and a point $y_1\in Y\setminus U$. Use $x,y_0$, and $y_1$ to define a function $f:X\to Y$ that is not continuous at $x$.